# SQL scenario. please help me with the query

Tags: oracle

Table `Doctor`:

| Doctor'name | Hospital name | dept |
| --- | --- | --- |
| rajib | A | EYE |
| Raj | null | null |
| sumit | B | BRAIN |
| saurabh | A | NOSE |
| Deepak | C | EYE |

I need a query to return those doctor names which are in same hospital but in a different dept.

I am new to SQL so I did not know how to approach this.

Comment: Hi Sherlock! Welcome! Am I right to assume you are using MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, it looks like self join would help.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with doctor (name, hospital, dept) as
  2    (select 'Rajib'  , 'A' , 'EYE'   from dual union all
  3     select 'Raj'    , null, null    from dual union all
  4     select 'Sumit'  , 'B' , 'BRAIN' from dual union all
  5     select 'Saurabh', 'A' , 'NOSE'  from dual union all
  6     select 'Deepak' , 'C' , 'EYE'   from dual
  7    )
```

Query:

```
  8  select a.name
  9  from doctor a join doctor b on a.hospital = b.hospital
 10                             and a.dept <> b.dept
 11                             and a.name <> b.name;

NAME
-------
Saurabh
Rajib

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  doctor,
  hospital,
  count(distinct dept) 
from ...
group by doctor,
  hospital
```

will give you the number of distinct departments for each doctor/hospital combination.

From there you could use an inline view or HAVING clause to limit the result however you like

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8888e6/3/0 online version of your code :-)